# Bind Checkboxlist with next 7 days Date Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have one `CheckboxList` in my page and I want to bind next 7 days (not today) value in my list dynamically. The value should me inserted in the format as shown in image below right side and when I display the page in `aspx` I want to display Date and Day as shown in the 1st image format.

All the dynamic binding perform using `Page_Load()`

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

[image: p]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I understand the scenario, you want to display list of next seven days in `dayOfWeek year-month-day` format. Here is one way to do it:

You `CheckBoxList` should look like this:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" DataTextField="date"   
        DataValueField="Id" /* Other Attributes */>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

And this should be the method to bind it:

```
public void BindCheckBoxListWithNextSevenDays()
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));

    for(int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(i, today.AddDays(i).ToString("dddd yyyy-MM-dd")); // (dddd yyyy-MM-dd) will return the date in following format (Wednesday 2020/02-05)
    }
    CheckBoxList1.DataSource = dt;  
    CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit #2:

```
public void BindCheckBoxList()
{
    IEnumerable<string> dates=Enumerable.Range(1, 7).Select(p=>DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(p).ToString("dddd HH:mm:ss"));
        CheckBoxList1.DataSource = dates;  
        CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
}
```

V#1

Create one method which will return the dates in a list in a format you like,

```
static IEnumerable<string> DatsOnInterval(DateTime from, DateTime thru,int dateInterval=1)
    {
        for(var day = from.Date; day.Date <= thru.Date; day = day.AddDays(dateInterval))
            yield return day.DayOfWeek.ToString()+" "+day.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    }
```

Call it like this and fill the checkbox list,

```
public static void Main()
    {

        try
        {
        var fromDt=DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        var toDt=fromDt.AddDays(7);
    var datas=DatsOnInterval(fromDt,toDt);
            foreach(var x in datas)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank sir for your reply. i try and give you the update.

Comment: I wouldn't go this way to concatenate the dates while I can use `ToString("dddd yyyy-MM-dd")` method.

Comment: Thank you to both sir @JamshaidKamran and "A_Sk" for your reply it is working now. i am fresher and in stack over flow i have 11 reputation so i have no idea my up vote counted or not but it is working thank to both sir.

Comment: @A_Sk sir i have tried your code it show me error  'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'date'.